# loadandverifyassembly error in Facebook script

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

I recently downloaded the latest FB SDK for unity and imported the asset package in my demo game project in unity ver. 4.0(windows)

As soon as i import all the files i face some errors in FB.cs script file .

Kindly let me know how to eradicate these following errors :

-> UnityEngine.Security does not contain a definition for LoadAndVerifyAssembly
in the line

```
   var assembly = Security.LoadAndVerifyAssembly(www.bytes);
```

Answer (score 1):

Ahh...the problem was unity itself..
I was using unity version 4.0 but the new Facebook SDK for unity has to have unity 4.1 + !!!